# C++ "Syntax error for identifier" (Although class is well defined)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm doing a little project in C++ to learn the programming language.

I'm defining every class in a separate header file and have its implementation in its own .cc file. I am also using guards for each header and including only what it uses.

This is the resume (over-simplified) of the program: I have 3 classes Board, Element and Sand. Sand is a type of Element and each Element has to implement a pure virtual function 'handle' that takes as a parameter the Board. Board has a simple method 'get' that returns an Element.

Here are the headers:

Board's

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include "Element.hh"

class Board
{
public:
    // Getters and Setters
    Element* get();
};

#endif
```

Element's

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include "Board.hh"

class Element
{
public:
    // Functions
    virtual void handle(Board* board) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Sand's

```
#ifndef SAND_H
#define SAND_H

#include "Element.hh"

class Sand : public Element
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Sand();
    // Functions
    void handle(Board* board);
};

#endif
```

Here are the errors:

```
Compilation Started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64

Board.cc

Element.hh(10,22): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Board'

Element.cc

Board.hh(10,9): error C2143: syntax error: ';' missing before '*'
Board.hh(10,9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Board.hh(10,16): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Sand.cc

Board.hh(10,9): error C2143: syntax error: ';' missing before '*'
Board.hh(10,9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Board.hh(10,16): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I already tried creating another project, deleting the .vs file, searching for explanations but I haven't found anything yet. Any help is appreciated!

(Also: all files are in the same folder (the default folder))

Comment: You need to forward declare your classes to avoid circular problems

Comment: `Board.hh` doesn't need to include `Element.hh`; a forward declaration is sufficient. Similarly, `Element.hh` doesn't need to include `Board.hh`. I expect the problem will resolve itself once you eliminate circular includes.

Comment: Thanks! I had already heard about forward declaration but thought it wouldn't be related to my problem. I will take a look into it now.

Comment: The important concept is never create a circular loop of headers.